# Solve $ f'(x)f(-x)=f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find all differentiable functions $ f$ from $ \mathbb{R}$ to $ \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ 
 f'(x)f(-x)=f(x)
$$
for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}$.

It's easy to check that this equation admits $f(x)=0$ and $ f(x)=1+e^x$ as solutions. The main difficulty comes from the appearance of $f(-x) $. For the case in which $f(x) \neq 0 $ for all $ x$, I've tried differentiating both sides of the equation and using the relation $ f'(-x) f'(x) = 1 $ to get rid of the term $ f'(-x) $ and obtained
$$
f'' f = f'^2 + f'
$$
But this equation seems to be more complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have made a very good attempt, as the ODE actually has a simple solution.

Notice that taking $g=f'$ yields $f''=g'=gg^*$ where $g^*=dg/df$ so $$ff''=f'(1+f')\implies fgg^*=g(1+g)\implies fg^*=1+g.$$ This is a separable equation with solution $$\int\frac{dg}{1+g}=\int\frac{df}f\implies \log(1+g)=\log f+c\implies g=Cf-1$$ for some constant $C$. Since $g=f'$ we have $$f'-Cf=-1\implies f(x)=De^{Cx}+\frac1C.$$

Comment: It should be noted that $f$ is indeed twice differentiable here as $f(x)=f'(x)f(-x)$ and $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ are differentiable. In general, it is possible that the product of two functions is differentiable but that one of the functions itself is not differentiable (take for example $g(x)=0$ and $h(x)=|x|$).

Comment: @Mathematician42 Good rigorous note.

Comment: Thanks! Very clear answer on your part! I was wondering why we can get to this second order differential equation in the first place, luckily the answer is not too difficult.

Comment: @Mathematician42 (and for others interested) To expand on their attempt, differentiating the original equation gives $f''(x)f(-x)-f'(x)f'(-x)=f'(x)$. The OP made the acute observation that $f'(x)f'(-x)=1$ and using $f(-x)=f(x)/f'(x)$ we obtain $f''(x)f(x)/f(x)=1+f'(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$f'' f = f'^2 + f'$$
Simply rewrite the ODE as:
$$\dfrac {f'' }{f'+1} = \dfrac {f'}{f}$$
$$\dfrac {(f'+1)' }{f'+1} = \dfrac {f'}{f}$$
Note that $\dfrac {f'}{f}=(\ln f)'$
$$(\ln (f'+1))'=(\ln f)'$$
Integrate both sides.